# How to show timestamp of when cell was last run in Jupyter VS code?

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, jupyter

Jupyter in VScode shows the cell execution time like this:

```
'1.9s'
```

but I would like a way to timestamp when the cell was run:

```
'1.9s on 4/28/22 10:30:05'
```

I had this function in Jupyter in the browser with an extension, but haven't found a way to show it in VSCode. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

I'm sorry to tell you that this function cannot be implemented at present. You can query the request of this function in [GitHub](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-jupyter/issues/8245).

Because the same function is also implemented in the form of extension on jupyter notebook, which means that the official has not yet started to do relevant content, so we'd better wait.

Comment: Thanks for the information! Hopefully someone has worked out a homebrew solution in the meantime that they would like to share!